# Can anyone translate this query into objection js query?

Tags: objection.js

I am trying to join two tables and trying to distinct the id of parent table.

> SELECT DISTINCT ON(management_company.id) * FROM management_company INNER JOIN buildings on m_id = management_company.id ;

Answer (score 0):

```
knex('management_company')
  .distinctOn('management_company.id')
  .join('buildings', 'm_id', 'management_company.id')
```

https://runkit.com/embed/komcgnpi80d9